# Calculating the sheaf $\mathcal I/\mathcal I^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

This should be an elementary question: say if I have a plane conic $C\subset \mathbb{P}^2$, then the ideal sheaf is $\mathcal{I} = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-2)$. How do I calculate $\mathcal{N}=\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2$? Is there a general way to calculate such $\mathcal{N}$?

Comment: What do you mean, "calculate"? What form of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @KReiser Say it can be expressed as $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(m)$ and $\mathcal{O}_{C}(n)$, I want to know what $m,n$ are.

Comment: In this case $N$ is just restriction of $I$ to $C$ and thus $n=-2$. Typically one uses $N$ for the dual in your situation.

Comment: @Mohan Could you explain in more detail? I don't understand why this is the restriction of $I$ to $C$...

Comment: You have an exact sequence, $0\to I^2\to I\to I/I^2\to 0$. Notice that $I=O(-2)$ and then $I/I^2=O(-2)_{|C}=O_C(-2)$.